# Did NATO instruct anti-government neo-Nazi groups in Ukraine on conducting diversions and waging guerilla?

Tags: politics, russia, ukraine

There are multiple claims in Russian press that in 2006 NATO in Estonia has instructed neo-Nazi anti-government paramilitary hate groups from Ukraine on how to conduct diversions and wage guerilla war. How much these claims are correct?

It is a well reported fact that NATO conducted instructage of Ukrainian neo-Nazi hate groups (particularly, the UNA-UNSO whose emblems are visible on the photos) in Estonia in 2006 on how to conduct diversions, terrorist acts and wage partisan war.

I wonder how does NATO justify this activity and whether it is well known in NATO countries?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[Source](http://www.sovr.krivbassinfo.com/cgi-bin/sovr.pl?lang=ru&action=showstat&sndir=2006_11&razd=4&stat=27)

There are also [videos](http://www.sovr.krivbassinfo.com/pict/2006_11/video.htm)

Comment: Judging by their eyes, these aren't Ukrainians, but hell-spawn! Either that, or they don't know how to do red-eye correction of their photos.

Comment: It is a "well reported fact"? Reported by who? Pravda? Please provide links.

Comment: @Shadur the link is there.

Comment: Is the "It is a well reported ..." bit a translation of a quote? If so, use markup to indicate a block quote.

Comment: I've skimmed through the photos and I don't see anyone in NATO uniform, nor any official military uniform for that matter.

Comment: sounds like more communist propaganda, blaming their opponents for doing what the communists have been doing for decades...

Comment: @vetec, this is Estonian officer, which is called a "NATO instructor", for instance http://www.sovr.krivbassinfo.com/pict/2006_11/06110061.jpg http://www.sovr.krivbassinfo.com/pict/2006_11/06110068.jpg

Comment: The pictures are taken at Kroonu Klubi, an Estonia based privately owned shooting range and training ground. This facility does provide military training services to whoever is willing to pay for them. It's owned by Martin Plaser, who served in Estonian Army and had been stationed in Afghanistan in 2006. According to Dmitrijs Savins, a member of the pirate crew which hijacked MV Arctic Sea in 2009, the said Plaser provided his training facility to the crew and personally trained the pirates.

Comment: @Quassnoi can you make it an answer please?

Comment: @Anixx: well, it does not answer whether or not NATO justifies this activity. I just wanted to add some background

Comment: There are two questions here, and the second one is nonsensical until the first one is answered.